# Dynamic border colors

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I want to have a set of dynamic textboxes that have border colors that match the color that's described by it. If the text of the textbox is "red", I want a red border. Here is how I am getting that behavior in a reprex that uses much of my original code:

```
library(shinyjs) # useShinyjs
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reprex"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      fluidRow(column(9, fileInput('manifest', 'Choose File',
                                    accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),
               column(3, actionButton("load_button", "Load", width = "100%"))),
      fluidRow(column(5, selectInput(inputId = "group_palette_input",
                                     label = "Palette Selector",
                                     choices = NA)),
               column(5, selectInput(inputId = "column_input",
                                     label = "Column Selector",
                                     choices = NA))),
      uiOutput("group_colors"),
      width=4),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Load the demo data on initialization and press the load button to update the file
  data <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$load_button, ignoreInit = FALSE, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    manifestName = ifelse(is.null(input$manifest$datapath), "file.txt", input$manifest$datapath)
    man = read.table(manifestName, sep = "\t", header = T, check.names=F, strip.white = T)
    data$manifest <- man[man$include, ]
  })
  
  # Update column selector
  observeEvent(data$manifest, { 
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "column_input")
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "column_input",
                      choices = names(data$manifest),
                      selected = "group") # All files should have a group column
  })
  
  # Update palette selector
  observeEvent(data$manifest, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "group_palette_input")
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "group_palette_input",
                      choices = rownames(brewer.pal.info),
                      selected = "Dark2")
  })
  
  groupIncludeManualPaletteInput <- eventReactive(input$column_input, {
    
    fullColors = brewer.pal(length(groups()), input$group_palette_input)
    lapply(1:length(groups()),
           function(groupIndex) {
             colorId = paste0(groups()[groupIndex], "_color")
             fluidRow(column(5, textInput(inputId = colorId,
                                          label = NULL,
                                          value = fullColors[groupIndex])),
                      column(1, checkboxInput(inputId = as.character(groups()[groupIndex]), # Numeric column causes issues, need to wrap with as.character
                                              label = groups()[groupIndex],
                                              value = TRUE),
                             style='padding:0px;')) # Removing padding puts the two columns closer together
           }) # End lapply
  })

  groups <- reactive(sort(unique(data$manifest[[input$column_input]])))
  
  # Update groupIncludeManualPaletteInput
  observeEvent(input$group_palette_input, {
    groupColorIds = paste0(groups(), "_color")
    fullColors = brewer.pal(length(groups()), input$group_palette_input)
    for (groupColorIndex in seq_along(groupColorIds)) {
      updateTextInput(session, groupColorIds[groupColorIndex], value = fullColors[groupColorIndex])
    }
  })
  
  # Vector of booleans to mask the included groups
  includedGroups <- reactive(unlist(map(as.character(groups()), ~input[[.x]]))) # unlist() allows includedGroups to be used as an index variable
  
  # Vector of characters of group names that are included
  currentGroups <- reactive(groups()[includedGroups()])
  
  # Vector of characters of color names that are included
  currentColors <- reactive(unlist(map(groups(), ~input[[paste0(.x, "_color")]])[includedGroups()]))
  
  output$group_colors <- renderUI(groupIncludeManualPaletteInput())
  
  # Make the borders of these textboxes match the color they describe
  # This is run twice when it works, but only once when it doesn't as a simple observe
  # As an observeEvent on groups(), only activates once and temporarily shows the border color; Adding in the req(input[[colorId]]) doesn't help
  # Same thing when the observation is on the groupIncludeManualPaletteInput()
  # Doubling the js code doesn't work
  # In the html, I can see that the border color is not being set
  # observing currentColors() is a dud too
  # Adding an if statement in the javascript doesn't change behavior.
  observe({
    lapply(seq_along(groups()),
           function(groupIndex) {
             colorId = paste0(groups()[groupIndex], "_color")
             cat("Made it into Loop,", input[[colorId]], '\n')
             cat(colorId, ': ', input[[colorId]], '\n\n')
             runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('", colorId, "').style.borderColor ='", input[[colorId]] ,"'"))
             runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('", colorId, "').style.borderWidth = 'thick'"))
           })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's what `file.txt` can look like, tab delimited:

```
group   disease celltype    include
1   HC  B   TRUE
2   SLE M   TRUE
2   HC  C   TRUE
```

Loading up, it all looks correct:

[image: Loading Up]

And then when I change what column I'm looking at, it does what I expect it to do, each textbox has a border with color described:

[image: New Column]

But if we go back to a column already chosen:

[image: Disaster!]

Then the border color is gone!

Looking at the react_log, I think it has something to do with re-initializing `input$1_color` and `input$2_color` in the `groupIncludeManualPaletteInput()` `eventReactive`. I also notice that when succesful, the `runjs()` section is run twice, but when unsuccessful, it only runs once.

As additional attempts to solve this issue, I thought that maybe the data types were the issue. I tried various combinations of using `groupIncludeManualPaletteInput` as a `reactiveValue`, but none seemed to mesh with `renderUI` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same input `ID` in `colorId` when you select the same group the second time. However, you need unique input `ID`s in shiny. I have added a counter to change it.  Try this.

```
library(shinyjs) # useShinyjs
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reprex"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      fluidRow(column(9, fileInput('manifest', 'Choose File',
                                   accept = c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', '.csv'))),
               column(3, actionButton("load_button", "Load", width = "100%"))),
      fluidRow(column(5, selectInput(inputId = "group_palette_input",
                                     label = "Palette Selector",
                                     choices = NULL)),
               column(5, selectInput(inputId = "column_input",
                                     label = "Column Selector",
                                     choices = rownames(brewer.pal.info)))),
      uiOutput("group_colors"),
      width=4),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cntr <- reactiveValues(val=0)
  # Load the demo data on initialization and press the load button to update the file
  # data <- reactiveValues()
  # observeEvent(eventExpr = input$load_button, ignoreInit = FALSE, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
  #   manifestName = ifelse(is.null(input$manifest$datapath), "file.csv", input$manifest$datapath)
  #   man = read.table(manifestName, sep = "\t", header = T, check.names=F, strip.white = T)
  #   data$manifest <- man[man$include, ]
  # })
  
  datamanifest <- reactive({
    req(input$manifest)
    read.csv(input$manifest$datapath, header = TRUE)
  })
  
  # Update column selector
  observeEvent(datamanifest(), { 
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "column_input")
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "column_input",
                      choices = names(datamanifest()),
                      selected = "group") # All files should have a group column
  })
  
  # Update palette selector
  observeEvent(datamanifest(), {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "group_palette_input")
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "group_palette_input",
                      choices = rownames(brewer.pal.info),
                      selected = "Dark2")
  })
  
  groupIncludeManualPaletteInput <- eventReactive(groups(), {
    req(input$group_palette_input)
    cntr$val <- cntr$val + 1
    fullColors = brewer.pal(length(groups()), input$group_palette_input)
    lapply(1:length(groups()),
           function(groupIndex) {
             colorId = paste0(groups()[groupIndex], "_color", cntr$val)
             fluidRow(column(5, textInput(inputId = colorId,
                                          label = NULL,
                                          value = fullColors[groupIndex])),
                      column(1, checkboxInput(inputId = as.character(groups()[groupIndex]), # Numeric column causes issues, need to wrap with as.character
                                              label = groups()[groupIndex],
                                              value = TRUE),
                             style='padding:0px;')) # Removing padding puts the two columns closer together
           }) # End lapply
  })
  
  groups <- eventReactive(input$column_input, {sort(unique(datamanifest()[[input$column_input]]))})
  
  # Update groupIncludeManualPaletteInput
  observeEvent(input$group_palette_input, {
    groupColorIds = paste0(groups(), "_color",cntr$val)
    fullColors = brewer.pal(length(groups()), input$group_palette_input)
    for (groupColorIndex in seq_along(groupColorIds)) {
      updateTextInput(session, groupColorIds[groupColorIndex], value = fullColors[groupColorIndex])
    }
  })
  
  # Vector of booleans to mask the included groups
  includedGroups <- eventReactive(groups(), {unlist(map(as.character(groups()), ~input[[.x]]))}) # unlist() allows includedGroups to be used as an index variable
  
  # Vector of characters of group names that are included
  currentGroups <- eventReactive(includedGroups(), {groups()[includedGroups()]})
  
  # Vector of characters of color names that are included
  currentColors <- reactive(unlist(map(groups(), ~input[[paste0(.x, "_color")]])[includedGroups()]))
  
  output$group_colors <- renderUI(groupIncludeManualPaletteInput())
  
  # Make the borders of these textboxes match the color they describe
  # This is run twice when it works, but only once when it doesn't as a simple observe
  # As an observeEvent on groups(), only activates once and temporarily shows the border color; Adding in the req(input[[colorId]]) doesn't help
  # Same thing when the observation is on the groupIncludeManualPaletteInput()
  # Doubling the js code doesn't work
  # In the html, I can see that the border color is not being set
  # observing currentColors() is a dud too
  # Adding an if statement in the javascript doesn't change behavior.
  observe({
    lapply(seq_along(groups()),
           function(groupIndex) {
             colorId = paste0(groups()[groupIndex], "_color",cntr$val)
             cat("Made it into Loop,", input[[colorId]], '\n')
             cat(colorId, ': ', input[[colorId]], '\n\n')
             runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('", colorId, "').style.borderColor ='", input[[colorId]] ,"'"))
             runjs(paste0("document.getElementById('", colorId, "').style.borderWidth = 'thick'"))
           })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! This does make the problem go away and I've marked you as the answer for now. But isn't this just skirting the problem down the road? It looks like I'm just continuously making new objects every time I change the selectInput(). Is there a better architecture I should be using?

Comment: @Jeff, You can accept the answer. This answer is based on your set-up on the server side. You are creating a new `textInput()` and `checkboxInput()`, every time you change the group variable. If you did that only once, then you do not need the counter value in the input ID.

Answer (score 0):

Following up with @YBS's response to my comment, I resorted to precomputing all the fields that could be made with the input file and using `conditionalPanel()` to selectively show them.

This has the theoretical disadvantage that another file cannot be loaded in, but in practice I'm not seeing it. But I can use @YBS's answer, a counter, to fix that should it ever stop being theoretical.

I also changed the section that makes the fields into a regular reactive dependent solely on data$manifest. I also changed the update function for the colors so they fits inside an observe instead of observeEvent. No other changes were necessary, but I hit a snag when I over-engineered around what I thought was a big update.